# How to call a function from a class in an another PHP file for routing purposes?

Tags: php

I have created a routing code but it doesn't work:

```
<?php
class APP 
{
    protected $controller = "home";
    protected $method = "index";
    protected $params = [];
    public function Run()
    {
        $url = $this->SplitURL();
        if(file_exists("../app/controller/".strtolower($url[0]).".php"))
        {
            $this->controller = strtolower($url[0]);
            unset($url[0]);
        }
        require "../app/controller/".$this->controller.".php";

        if(isset($url[1]))
        {
            if(method_exists($this->controller, $url[1]))
            {
                $this->method = $url[1];
                unset($url[1]);
            }
        }
        //array_values function resets array's empty indexes
        $this->params = array_values($url);
        //This function calls methods in controller

        call_user_func_array([$this->controller, $this->method], $this->params);

    }

    private function SplitURL()
    {
        if($_GET == null)
        {
            return array("home/index");
        }
        else
        {
            return explode("/", filter_var(trim($_GET['url'], '/')),FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);
        }
    }
}
```

The code for home controller (home.php) is:

```
<?php
class Home
{
    public function index()
    {
        $this->View("gallery/index");
    }
    public function View($view, $data = '')
    {
        if(file_exists("../app/views/".$view.".php"))
        {
            include "../app/views/".$view.".php";
        }
    }
}
?>
```

But when I test it, there is **fatal error** that says:

> Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: call_user_func_array(): Argument #1
> ($function) must be a valid callback, non-static method Home::index()
> cannot be called statically

How can I fix it?

Comment: you should define index as public static function index

Comment: When I change it to public static function, it shows error in $this

Comment: Since you are using PHP 5.6+ *(8.0 since PHP is throwing an exception instead of a warning)*, you can simplify by using the [spread operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.variable-arg-list) `...`  instead of  `call_user_func_array()`. First declare  `$callback = [new $this->controller, $this->method];` followed by `$callback(...$this->params);`. I also recommend using [`is_callable($callback)`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-callable.php), to ensure the specified method exists and is `public`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an instance of `$this->controller`:

```php
$controller = new $this->controller;
call_user_func_array([$controller, $this->method], $this->params);
```

**Updated:**

> **@Alex:**
> explain that why I need to instantiate a variable before using that function

I guess in the old versions of php it did not matter that the first argument of the `call_user_func_array` function was a `static` or `non-static` function, but in the current versions must do same as normal calling the classes and functions: No need to create an instance of a class to call `static` function, and for `non-static` functions such as your `index action` in the `home controller` requires create an instance of it class.

Comment: You are missing the `new` keyword needed to instantiate the object, `$controller = new $this->controller;`, otherwise `$controller` will remain a `string` and only permit calling `static` methods  See example: https://3v4l.org/IIoon

Comment: Thanks for your reminder, yes I forgot the `new` keyword. **Answer updated**

Comment: Thanks, it solved the problem. Now, when I enter controller name it redirects to home controller and index method. The problem is that if I type controller and method name (home/index) it shows my page without css loadings. Why?

Comment: And please explain that why I need to instantiate a variable before using that function. Thanks

Comment: @Alex For loading css: Please take a look to your `Browser->DevTools->Network monitoring` and see what is css link address? If it status is 404, then edit your css link address in view file (Link it from root like _http://example.com/assets/styles.css_)

Comment: @Sina Kadkhodaei I used chrome's inspect tool and the style section was empty. I don't know why css loads when I enter just controller name but when I provide both controller and method name in the url, css does not load

Comment: @Alex For css: Please show your view rendering (or handling) code with more informations in a new question or update this page question.

Comment: @Alex The reason for needing to instantiate the object before calling the method is due to the PHP [8.0 changes](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration80.incompatible.php), where only static methods can be called from the callable array when the class name is a string, otherwise an exception is thrown.  In PHP < 8, a Strict Standards warning would be emitted, despite still working. To avoid the issue you would need to define the method as `public static function` instead, which would no longer support the context of `$this` .